# non-negative measurable functions in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In the measure theory, I'm trying to show if h=f+g
integral of h is equal to the sum of integral of f and integral of g.
Before this step, I want to express h+ and h- in terms of f+, f-, g+, g-, but cannot figure out how to express in a concise way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited my question.

Comment: I doubt you "can", mainly because you run into the fundamental issue of asking when $f\ge g$ while you only know when $f\ge 0$ and when $g\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $h = h^+ - h^- = (f+g)^+ - (f+g)^-$, and you also have that $h = f+g =(f^+ - f^-) + (g^+ - g^-) =(f^+ + g^+) - (f^- + g^-)$, i.e.
$$ h = (f+g)^+ - (f+g)^- = (f^+ + g^+) - (f^- + g^-) $$
Which implies
$$(f+g)^+ + (f^- + g^-) = (f^+ + g^+) + (f+g)^-  \tag1 $$

Now notice that all the terms between parentheses in $(1) $ are nonnegative functions, so by additivity of Lebesgue integral for nonnegative measurable functions it holds that :
$$\begin{align}\int\left((f+g)^+ + (f^- + g^-)\right) &= \int\left((f^+ + g^+) + (f+g)^-\right)\\
\implies \int(f+g)^+ + \int (f^- + g^-) &= \int (f^+ + g^+) + \int(f+g)^- \\
\implies \int(f+g)^+ - \int(f+g)^- &= \int (f^+ + g^+) - \int (f^- + g^-) \tag2\end{align} $$

Putting $(2)$ together with the definition of $h = f+g$ we get :
$$\begin{align}\int h = \int(f+g) &= \int\left((f+g)^+ - (f + g)^-\right) \\
&= \int(f+g)^+ - \int(f+g)^- \text{ (Lebesgue integral for signed functions)}\\
&= \int (f^+ + g^+) - \int (f^- + g^-) \text{ (By equation (2))}\\
&=\int f^+ + \int g^+ - \int f^- - \int g^-\text{ (Additivity for nonnegative functions)}\\
&= \int f^+ - \int f^- + \int g^+  - \int g^-\\
&= \int f + \int g \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare\end{align} $$